# Custom control can only be instantiated once

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I am new to WPF and custom controls.

I have implemented a custom control in VB with WPF and MVVM based on Davids example: http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/

I have a custom control libary and a reference to my project to implement my control.
I implement my contol in the View via XAML:

**EDIT:**

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UIControls;assembly=UIControls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="LoginView"
x:Name="LoginView"
Width="457" Height="216" Visibility="Visible" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <l:ExpandedTextBox Name="UsernameText" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,5,5" />

</Grid>
```

When I instantiate my custom control once everything works fine,

```
 <l:ExpandedTextBox Name="UsernameText" />
```

but as soon as I try to instantiate it twice in the same View I get an error code:

```
Error 1 Cannot create an instance of "ExpandedTextBox"
```

**EDIT:**

The XAML code with the error looks like this:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UIControls;assembly=UIControls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="LoginView"
x:Name="LoginView"
Width="457" Height="216" Visibility="Visible" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <l:ExpandedTextBox Name="UsernameText" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,5,5" />

   <l:ExpandedTextBox Name="Password" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,5,5" />

</Grid>
```

I named the second custom control different and my first custom control still works fine.
The error only appears with the second custom control "Password".

The corresponding Generic.xaml file looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UIControls">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_Background" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_Foreground" Color="Black" />
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_Border" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE3E9EF" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_BorderMouseOver" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF5C97C1" Offset="0.05" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFB9D7EB" Offset="0.07" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC7E2F1" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBorder" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBackground" Color="White" />
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBorder_MouseOver" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5F4FC" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBackground_MouseOver" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE7F5FD" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD2EDFC" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFB6E3FD" Offset="0.51" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9DD5F3" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBorder_MouseDown" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5F4FC" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBackground_MouseDown" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE7F5FD" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD2EDFC" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFB6E3FD" Offset="0.51" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9DD5F3" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExpandedTextBox_LabelTextColor" Color="Gray" />



<Style x:Key="{x:Type l:ExpandedTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type l:ExpandedTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_Background}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_Border}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_Foreground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="LabelText" Value="Username" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="LabelTextColor" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_LabelTextColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:ExpandedTextBox}">

                <Border x:Name="Border"
                   Padding="2"
                   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                   BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                   BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Grid.Column="0" />

                        <Label x:Name="LabelText"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelTextColor}"
                          Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelText}"
                          Padding="2,0,0,0"
                          FontStyle="Italic" />

                        <Border x:Name="PART_SearchIconBorder"
                          Grid.Column="2"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                          BorderThickness="1"
                          Padding="1"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBorder}"
                          Background="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_SearchIconBackground}">

                            <Image x:Name="SearchIcon"
                                Stretch="None"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Source="pack://application:,,,/UIControls;component/Images/clear.png" />

                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_BorderMouseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ExpandedTextBox_BorderMouseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasText" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LabelText" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SearchIconBorder" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" SourceName="PART_SearchIconBorder" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="HasClicked" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_SearchIconBorder" Value="#FFF0F5" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The ExpandedTextBox VB file looks like this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class ExpandedTextBox
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.TextBox


Public Property LabelTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", GetType(String), GetType(ExpandedTextBox))
Public Property LabelTextColorProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelTextColor", GetType(Brush), GetType(ExpandedTextBox))
Public Property HasTextPropertyKey As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HasText", GetType(Boolean), GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New PropertyMetadata())
Public Property HasTextProperty As DependencyProperty = HasTextPropertyKey
Public Property HasClickedPropertyKey As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HasClicked", GetType(Boolean), GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New PropertyMetadata())
Public Property HasClickedProperty As DependencyProperty = HasClickedPropertyKey

Public Property HasClicked As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(HasClickedProperty), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(HasClickedProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    If HasClicked = True Then
        Me.Text = ""
    Else
        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    End If

End Sub


Public Property LabelText As String
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(LabelTextProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LabelTextColor As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Brush)
        SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property HasText As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(HasTextProperty), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(HasTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Shared Sub New()
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(ExpandedTextBox)))
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    HasText = Text.Length <> 0
End Sub


End Class
```

Why can't I create the same custom control twice in my view ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: There should be no reason why you can add as many copies of your user control to your window as you want. That's the point of user controls! There isn't enough code here to tell you what you problem might be.

Comment: You post a lot of information but did NOT include the XAML that is throwing the error.

Comment: You're probably doing something in the constructor that you can't do twice in the same appdomain.  Open UIControls.vbproj in a second instance of Visual Studio and attach the debugger to the first instance and then try putting two ExpandedTextBoxes on the same View again.

Comment: I edited the question with all the code. Hopefully this helps in understanding the problem guys. Thanks in advance again !

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but aren't dependency property definitions supposed to be static/Shared?

Comment: @ Rich - Thanks for your answer, that was the problem ! I will post the correct code for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem with the comment of Rich. Thanks for that !

The problem were the dependcy properties, which weren't set at shared in the VB file. The new working file looks like this.

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class ExpandedTextBox
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.TextBox


Public Shared Property LabelTextProperty As DependencyProperty
Public Shared Property LabelTextColorProperty As DependencyProperty
Public Shared Property HasTextPropertyKey As DependencyProperty
Public Shared Property HasTextProperty As DependencyProperty
Public Shared Property HasClickedPropertyKey As DependencyProperty
Public Shared Property HasClickedProperty As DependencyProperty


Shared Sub New()
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(ExpandedTextBox)))
    LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", GetType(String), GetType(ExpandedTextBox))
    LabelTextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelTextColor", GetType(Brush), GetType(ExpandedTextBox))
    HasTextPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.Register("HasText", GetType(Boolean), GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New PropertyMetadata())
    HasTextProperty = HasTextPropertyKey
    HasClickedPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.Register("HasClicked", GetType(Boolean), GetType(ExpandedTextBox), New PropertyMetadata())
    HasClickedProperty = HasClickedPropertyKey
End Sub


Public Property HasClicked As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(HasClickedProperty), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(HasClickedProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    If HasClicked = True Then
        Me.Text = ""
    Else
        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    End If

End Sub


Public Property LabelText As String
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(LabelTextProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LabelTextColor As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Brush)
        SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property HasText As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(HasTextProperty), Boolean)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(HasTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property



Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    HasText = Text.Length <> 0
End Sub


End Class
```

Thanks for all the contribution !

Awesome StackOverflow !

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you specified `x:Name` attribute of `ExpendedTextBox` UserControl.

Grid you are adding controls to is aware of their names, that's why it throws exception if it detects multiple controls in its children collection with the same x:Name.

Comment: We actually resolved the problem. We had the same idea EvAlex but could not resolve the problem with it. Instead the real problem were the dependency properties, which weren't set to shared !